# How to convince groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder to create a node whose name is 'use'

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

SVG defines an element named `use` and I am trying to generate an SVG file using `groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder` that takes advantage of this tag:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/defs-element.html

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

xml.svg {
    defs {
        g(id:"shape") {
            rect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50)
            circle(cx:50, cy:50, r:50)
        }
    }

    use("xlink:href":"#shape", x:50,  y:50")
}
```

However `use` is also a keyword in groovy. How do I escape it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure those methods are official however they work:

**v1:**

```groovy
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()

xml.svg {
    defs {
        g(id:"shape") {
            rect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50)
            circle(cx:50, cy:50, r:50)
        }
    }
    createNode('use',["xlink:href":"#shape", x:50,  y:50])
    //nested elements could be here
    nodeCompleted('svg','use')
}
```

**v2:**

```groovy
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()

xml.svg {
    defs {
        g(id:"shape") {
            rect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50)
            circle(cx:50, cy:50, r:50)
        }
    }

    doInvokeMethod('use','use',[["xlink:href":"#shape", x:50,  y:50], { 
        /*nested elements could be here*/ 
    } ])
}
```

**v3:**

we could redefine `getName` method that is responsible to do names mapping or check escaping rules.

```groovy
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class MyMarkupBuilder  extends groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder{
    def getName(String name){
        if(name.startsWith('__'))return name.substring(2)
        return name
    }
}

def xml = new MyMarkupBuilder()

xml.svg {
    defs {
        g(id:"shape") {
            rect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50)
            circle(cx:50, cy:50, r:50)
        }
    }
    __use("xlink:href":"#shape", x:50,  y:50)
}
```